# Why are the visited days no longer available on the profile page?

Tags: support, bug, feature-request, design

Earlier on the profile page, when we clicked on the calendar icon, we used to get the calendar displaying the days that we visited marked with green and the days we didn't visit without green...

Now after a couple of weeks, I guess ... I am unable to view the visited days exactly?

Is it only me or everyone is getting the same error?

**Image for reference**

[image]

The marked icon is used to give that calendar dropdown.

**Like this**

[image]

Is this feature removed? If so please consider this as a feature request.

Comment: [Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive): *"The consecutive visit calendar UI has gone away. This is some super legacy UI that isn’t remotely mobile-friendly. The statistic will continue to be displayed for badge-earning purposes, but I think it’s a potentially toxic metric."*

Comment: I never had much use for it. All days were always green for me. I have 882 days consecutive.

Comment: It makes sense now @Dharman ... :) I was curious about the day I broke my continuous visit strike ... I was like what I was doing that day? what was the important thing the held me from not visiting the site :)

Comment: Vanity metrics considered harmful(?). To be consistent, [the user leagues](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=week) should be removed as well.